# CD to directory, where the path is in a file

Tags: windows, scripting

I have a directory path stored in a text file, and I need to CD to that directory in a script but don't know how. I was hoping it would be something like

```
cat FILE | cd
```

but its not that easy.

This is a windows environment btw, in unix/linux it is easy:

```
cd `cat FILE`
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set /p dirname=<FILE
cd %dirname%
```

The documentation for `set` (for XP) can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/set.mspx).

> **/p** : Sets the value of variable to a
>   line of input.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, it is that easy:

```
Get-Content FILE | Set-Location
```

Or if you prefer the CMD aliases:

```
type FILE | cd
```

Or if you prefer the shorthand PowerShell aliases:

```
gc FILE | sl
```

Comment: I have cygwin with bash installed ... but I cant use anything like that, it needs to be pure windows stuff unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pure windows stuff".  PowerShell is written by Microsoft and is available as a free download.  If you mean that it has to be a solution that is pre-installed on some version of Windows then you should probably retag your question to include "cmd" or "batch" as a tag.